# Fibonacci induction

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

The question requires strong induction.

Prove that a sum of a set of Fibonacci numbers can represent any natural number $n$.

For example, $49$ is the sum of a set $(34, 13, 2)$ of Fibonacci numbers.

I understand how this makes sense, but I wasn't sure what values to use as the base case.

Comment: Wouldn't you either use $(1)$ or $(0)$ as the base case, depending on if you defined the Naturals to be include $0$ or not?

Comment: If my base cases are 1, 2, 3, then the sets of Fibonacci numbers would only contain one element

Comment: I don't think so. If you start the Fibonacci Numbers at $1$ being the first and $1$ being the second, then regardless of the fact that the only number the $\{F_1\}$ can sum to is $1$ you can still produce infinitely many Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need strong induction to prove this. Consider the set of all numbers that **cannot** be expressed as a sum of Fibonacci numbers.

If this set were non-empty, it would have a smallest element $n_0$.

Now let $F_n$ be the largest Fibonacci number $< n_0$. Then $n_0 - F_n < n_0$ and thus $n_0 - F_n$ is a sum of Fibonacci numbers. Thus $n_0$ is also a sum of Fibonacci numbers. Contradiction.

Therefore there is no number that is not a sum of Fibonacci numbers.

**Added:** It is possible to prove that each $n \ge 2$ can be uniquely written as a sum of distinct Fibonacci numbers such that no two consecutive Fibonacci numbers appear in the sum. For example, $20 = 13 + 5 + 2$ and $200 = 144 + 55 + 1$ ([Fibonacci Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_coding)). Proof by strong induction.

Comment: The question requires it to be proved by strong induction, though

Comment: Fortunately, the least-number principle used in this answer is easily equivalent to strong induction, so the answer can be written in a way that uses strong induction.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question said "the sum of a set of Fibonacci numbers" not just "a sum of Fibonacci numbers"; the difference is that there should be no repeated summands. (If repetitions were allowed, you could just use a sum of 1's.) So the answer needs to be supplemented with a (fortunately easy) argument that $F_n$ is not needed as a summand in $n_0-F_n$ (because in fact $F_n>n_0-F_n$).

Comment: My bad; I edited the question now. I understand that I should do n - Fk, where Fk is the largest Fibonacci number in a set. But then I am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Basically, what you did is the contrapositive of the strong induction.